# Associate CGAffineTransformRotation to CGAffineTransformTranslation

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform, quartz-core

I am trying to rotate a custom view (VIEWA) added on a parent view based on touch gesture using CGAffineTransformRotate. Everything is working fine. Now, I have another view(VIEWB) added on the parent view which should follow the path traced by a corner of the VIEWA while being rotated.

What i did was to calculate the new coordinates of the VIEWB from the VIEWA transformation matrix and translated the subview. i.e

```
VIEWA.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(startTransform, -angleDifference+M_PI_2);
CGFloat cosa = VIEWA.transform.a;
CGFloat msinb = VIEWA.transform.b;
CGFloat sinc = VIEWA.transform.c;
CGFloat cosd = VIEWA.transform.d;

CGFloat newX = VIEWB.center.x * cosa + VIEWB.center.y * msinb;
CGFloat newY = VIEWB.center.x * sinc + VIEWB.center.y * cosd;

CGFloat xdiff = newX - VIEWB.center.x;
CGFloat ydiff = newY - VIEWB.center.y;

VIEWB.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(VIEWB.transform, xdiff, ydiff);
```

But i could not get what i wanted. Can somebody help me ?

**Update:**

This is what I'm trying to do :(red dot is **A** and black popup is **B**):

[image]

Comment: An image or something of what you are trying to achieve would be helpful. I don't get what B is supposed to do.

Comment: HI David,pfa the image below: red circle with red dot is VIEWA and black popup showing number is VIEWB  http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=1d77fa6      Thank u

Comment: Why not have the black popover as a subview of the red dot and apply  -angle rotation to it?

Comment: I will do the same now. The problem is that the VIEWA is not actually a View but a custom layer that i am rotating while VIEWB is a subview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you rotate view A but the red circle stays at a fixed position in view A's coordinate system.  Thus the center of the red circle, in view A's coordinate system, should be something like easy to compute, like this:

```
CGPoint redCircleCenterInViewA = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(viewA.bounds), 12);
```

You can simply convert that point to the parent view's coordinate system, like this:

```
CGPoint redCircleCenterInParentView = [viewA convertPoint:redCircleCenterInViewA
    toView:viewA.superview];
```

Then you can set view B's center to that point, minus half of view B's height:

```
viewB.center = CGPointMake(redCircleCenterInParentView.x,
    redCircleCenterInParentView.y - viewB.frame.size.height / 2);
```

#### UPDATE

I see that you actually have **layer** A, not **view** A.  That only requires a slight modification.  The message you send to a layer to convert coordinates is slightly different than the message you send to a view.

```
CALayer *layerA = ...;
UIView *parentView = ...;
UIView *viewB = ...;

CGPoint redCircleCenterInLayerA = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerA.bounds), 12);

CGPoint redCircleCenterInParentView = [layerA convertPoint:redCircleCenterInLayerA
    toLayer:parentView.layer];

viewB.center = CGPointMake(redCircleCenterInParentView.x,
    redCircleCenterInParentView.y - viewB.frame.size.height / 2);
```

Note that there are also `convertPoint:fromLayer:` and `convertPoint:fromView:` messages.  Don't let Xcode autocomplete the wrong one or you will be scratching your head!

Comment: I assume this works. Let me give a try ad get back to u. Thanks a lot

Comment: hurrah! It is working with no performance issues. Thanks a lot rob